# Typescript: Using spread operator to merge several Maps into a new Map results in empty Object

Tags: typescript

In the following sample code:

```
let m1 = new Map<string, PolicyDocument>([
        [
            "key1",
            new PolicyDocument({
                statements: [
                    new PolicyStatement({
                        actions: ["sqs:PublishMessage"],
                        effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                        resources: ["aa:bb:cc"]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ]
    ]);

    let m2 = new Map<string, PolicyDocument>([
        [
            "key2",
            new PolicyDocument({
                statements: [
                    new PolicyStatement({
                        actions: ["sqs:GetMessage"],
                        effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                        resources: ["aa:bb:cc"]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ]
    ]);

    let m3 = new Map<string, PolicyDocument>([
        [
            "key3",
            new PolicyDocument({
                statements: [
                    new PolicyStatement({
                        actions: ["sqs:DeleteMessage"],
                        effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                        resources: ["aa:bb:cc"]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ]
    ]);

    const result: Map<string, PolicyDocument> = {
        ...m1,
        ...m2,
        ...m3
    };
    console.log(result);
```

Can someone help me understand why `result` is empty Object instead of having the three key,value pairs?
I'm overlooking some concept in typescript.

I use the native Map type provided without using any imports.

#### Edit

Thanks for sharing the correct way to merge Maps, that was helpful. My question is about

1. why above code doesn't throw compile-time error?
2. why above merge approach doesn't work?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77582553/typescript-using-spread-operator-to-merge-several-maps-into-a-new-map-results-i#comment136773397_77582553) [example](https://tsplay.dev/mpKbBN)

Comment: Thanks, I was ,in fact, using new Map with spread operator afterwards and it worked. I was confused as to why curly braces syntax doesn't work even though code compiles without issues. If curly braces is not same as Map, I'd expect compiler to not let me assign it to a Map type vairable

Comment: ① Please provide a [mre] by replacing any undeclared types like `PolicyDocument` with native things... you could probably demonstrate with `number` instead of `PolicyDocument`.  This will make is easier for us to test in our own IDEs and simplify the example.

Comment: ② TS does not currently know how to model non-enumerable properties (see [ms/TS#9726](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726)). When you spread objects, only enumerable properties are copied, which excludes class methods, but TS will think the methods are there, so it doesn't catch the error.  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up a full answer explaining (after you [edit] to provide a real [mre] to work with).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Presumably this question is asking "why doesn't this work" or "why doesn't TS complain if this doesn't work" and not "how can I change my code to do this correctly"?  @PhalanX, if so, please [edit] the question to make that clear... and then we can vote to reopen

Comment: Thanks jcalz. I have edited and requested for reopen. Your answer regarding 'enumerable properties' probably answers it. Just that I'll need to do some more study on what even are enumerable properties and understand difference between map vs curly braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your merge approach doesn't work because spreading `Map`s doesn't copy anything**

[Object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) of the form `{...m1, ...m2, ...m3}` copies objects' [*own enumerable* properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties). It only copies objects' *own* properties; it does not copy properties that objects [inherit through their prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#inheriting_properties).  It only copies objects' *enumerable* properties, such as those created via [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) or as [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields); it does not include non-enumerable properties like [class methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#method_definitions_in_classes) or [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#using_getters_in_classes).  If we inspect a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object via [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor#description) and [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf), we see the following:

```
const map = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]);
console.log(map) // Map (2) {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
displayProps(map);
/* 
get: inherited non-enumerable
has: inherited non-enumerable
set: inherited non-enumerable
delete: inherited non-enumerable
keys: inherited non-enumerable
values: inherited non-enumerable
clear: inherited non-enumerable
forEach: inherited non-enumerable
entries: inherited non-enumerable
size: inherited non-enumerable
constructor: inherited non-enumerable
toString: inherited non-enumerable
toLocaleString: inherited non-enumerable
valueOf: inherited non-enumerable
hasOwnProperty: inherited non-enumerable
isPrototypeOf: inherited non-enumerable
propertyIsEnumerable: inherited non-enumerable
__defineGetter__: inherited non-enumerable
__defineSetter__: inherited non-enumerable
__lookupGetter__: inherited non-enumerable
__lookupSetter__: inherited non-enumerable 
*/
```

Look at that; it has *no* own enumerable properties (indeed none of its properties are either own or enumerable), so spreading a `Map` object doesn't copy anything at all:

```
const copy = {...map};
console.log(copy) // {}
displayProps(copy);
/*
toString: inherited non-enumerable
toLocaleString: inherited non-enumerable
valueOf: inherited non-enumerable
hasOwnProperty: inherited non-enumerable
isPrototypeOf: inherited non-enumerable
propertyIsEnumerable: inherited non-enumerable
__defineGetter__: inherited non-enumerable
__defineSetter__: inherited non-enumerable
__lookupGetter__: inherited non-enumerable
__lookupSetter__: inherited non-enumerable
constructor: inherited non-enumerable
*/
```

And so merging `Map`s via spread doesn't work at runtime.

---

**TypeScript didn't catch the mistake of assigning the result to `Map` because it can't really track whether properties are own or enumerable**

So if `{...map}` is equivalent to `{}`, why doesn't TypeScript complain when you assign it to a `Map` type?

```
const result: Map<string, number>
  = { ...map, ...map, ...map }; // no error
```

The problem is that the TypeScript type system currently has no way to express that a property is own/inherited or enumerable/non-enumerable.  There is a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#9726](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726) requesting some way to specify this information.  Until and unless something like this is implemented, it's not part of the language.  So for all TypeScript knows, a `Map`'s properties are *all* own and enumerable... and indeed it would be possible to write your own object which looks to TypeScript exactly like a `Map` instance except that its properties are all own and enumerable:"

```
const e: [string, number] = ["", 0]
const o: Map<string, number> = {
  get: () => 1, has: () => true, set: () => o,
  delete: () => true, keys: () => [""][Symbol.iterator](),
  values: () => [0][Symbol.iterator](), clear: () => { },
  forEach: () => { }, entries: () => [e][Symbol.iterator](),
  size: 2, [Symbol.iterator]: () => [e][Symbol.iterator](),
  [Symbol.toStringTag]: ""
}

const p: Map<string, number> = { ...o }
displayProps(p);
/* get: own enumerable
has: own enumerable
set: own enumerable
delete: own enumerable
keys: own enumerable
values: own enumerable
clear: own enumerable
forEach: own enumerable
entries: own enumerable
size: own enumerable */
```

Since the compiler can't tell the difference between these cases, we run into this limitation where spreading `Map` instances looks like a valid operation to TypeScript.

See [microsoft/TypeScript#33081](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33081) which was specifically raised about this exact issue with spreading `Map` instances.  It was closed as a duplicate of microsoft/TypeScript#9726.

---

There you go; we're kind of stuck.  `Map` instances cannot be copied via object spread, and TypeScript isn't smart enough to catch it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.3.2#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-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-wvtwL87h9pOAAMSR202OA0K7HuI9PfCzx8gecInBivB8h7oKnNAn46HheDAhw58Up9kPsnD5yEArX+8t-mIcxfUV-D4i8kgREclYPeTBGiETOFMOeJ9X45HLlfZ+EQV6gPAfQRgUDepIFgUkeB6Aa78WQTfcIUgEGkCbhsEh38yFAmgNqABKCYAgLARArB0DcHTHwTYCh6Be4CinGONhmDsGCDwTQoBLD0HsLETA7h8DOAyNEQjEKCQAAqSBkjullNINeTg8Cb0tNvNRu996vWDjgckIALzg2vPoAweBazx0Tj6ZWl9CSXCNo-NxVt36wBoL47W-9AkuGVkgzx1c+LmyCUbKh0lQmqGVh3aisSmoCMSV44s6AbpAA)